# Is there a way to add an include path to Qt Creator that applies globally to all projects?

Tags: qt, qmake, include-path

I need Qt Creator to store some global include paths that will apply to all projects. Is there currently any way to do this?

The reason I am trying to do this is because on Windows, there is no standard location for include files - so the only way to add an include path is to specify the absolute path to the folder in the `.pro` file. This becomes a nightmare when the `.pro` file is checked into version control.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set CPATH & friends environment variables so mingw will use them to search include files:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Environment-Variables.html#Environment-Variables

Comment: Is there a similar variable for library paths?

Comment: Never mind... I [found it](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/gcc/Environment-Variables.html#Environment-Variables). Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how "recommended" this is but you can add an `INCLUDEPATH +=` to `qmake.conf` in `<qt install directory>\qt\mkspecs\default`

Comment: Hmmm... that's an option. I'm not opposed to playing around with global settings like that.

Comment: Hmm, that's too bad. I did a test for myself here by removing a path from my .pro file which resulted in a compile failure. I added the include path to the qmake.conf and the compile succeeded. This is a shadey area of Qt functionality for me so I'm not too surprised :)